# SQL COALESCE adding leading character

Tags: sql, coalesce

I am trying to build a concatenated string (a version number) based off of rows in a temp table. When trying to run it as a standalone script, I am having no issues, but when it is executed as part of a stored procedure, I am having issues.

Here is what I am doing: I have a temp table with the following structure:

```
    ElementId     |Element
    ---------------------
    1             |2
    2             |0
    3             |1
    4             |4
```

I am using the following command to concatenate the values:

```
declare @nNewVersion        VARCHAR(50) 

SELECT @nNewVersion = COALESCE(@nNewVersion + '.' ,'') + Element 
FROM #TEMP_VERSION
ORDER BY ElementID
```

When I run it by itself, I get

```
2.0.1.4
```

However, when it is run through the stored procedure, I get the following:

```
.2.0.1.4
```

What could be causing that extra "." to be applied to the beginning of the string?

Edit: Actual code snippet from SP - in this case, release version would be 2.0.1.3

```
DECLARE @nCurrentVersion    VARCHAR(50),
        @nNewVersion        VARCHAR(50) 

SELECT TOP 1 @nCurrentVersion = ReleaseVersion
FROM ReleaseDetail
ORDER BY ReleaseDetailID Desc

select * 
into #TEMP_VERSION
from dbo.ufn_SplitString(@nCurrentVersion, '.', 0)

UPDATE #TEMP_VERSION
SET Element = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(Element as int) + 1)
WHERE ElementID = 4

SELECT @nNewVersion = COALESCE(@nNewVersion + '.' ,'') + Element 
FROM #TEMP_VERSION
ORDER BY ElementID
```

@nNewVersion is then used in an insert statement

Comment: Probably an extra row in the table with an empty string or the variable is being set to an empty string before you use it when in the proc rather than being null. This method of string concatenation is not guaranteed to work anyway.

Comment: This was my initial guess as well - I wound up writing it to a table I could access outside of the stored procedure, but there was no blank row/row containing a blank string.

Comment: So is `@nNewVersion` an empty string immediately before the concatenation? The code relies on it being null. Which is different from empty string.

Comment: @nNewVersion is declared right before the concatenation - it is not set to an empty string at any point.

Comment: Well in that case use a guaranteed method like XML PATH instead of an approach which is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot!

Comment: Could you post a few sample on how are you using it in your SP?

Comment: Just occurred to me that `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` could cause this (.i.e. If it is set to `off`) but even if that is the reason use some other method.

Comment: McNets - see updated question